# Remove unwanted left offset from document

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I am trying to create grids of size 1 in. X 1 in. using tikz. However, even after setting the `margin` and `bindingoffset` to 0, my grids do not exactly start at `y = 0`. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in, paperwidth=8.15in, margin={0in,0in}, bindingoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,26}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [step=1in, black, line width=0.01in] (0,0) grid (6in, 6in);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \newpage
    }
\end{document}
```

This is a snapshot of page 1 (all pages are like this ---both evens and odds). As you can see, there is an offset on the left. How can I make it start it exactly at top left edge of the paper?

[image: Image showing extra whitespace on the left of a tikzpicture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindingoffset` is not needed in this case. What's pushing the `tikzpicture` is simply the `\indent`.

Adding `\setlength\parindent{0cm}` to the preamble removes the whitespace in all pages of the document.

A bit secondary but a quick tip: You can add `[x=1in, y=1in]` to the `tikzpicture`, so you don't need to specify this in the grid like `(6in,6in)`. Of course, you can always use another unit of measurement, but if you only use inches, then it should help you by having less to type.

See the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in, paperwidth=8.15in, margin={0in,0in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}% added

\begin{document}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,26}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in, y=1in]
            \draw [step=1in, black, line width=0.01in] (0,0) grid (6,6);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \newpage
    }
\end{document}
```